# Retrieve multiple values from SQL db to use in JavaScript Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm using the following script for an input autocomplete feature. I retrieve 3 columns of data from a MYSQL database. The script is great at displaying 1 column, 'title', but I want to use the others, 'slug' and 'id', to build a clickable URL for each result.

What I've tried so far hasn't worked. How do I make slug and id available to use?

```
MIN_LENGTH = 2;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#keyword").keyup(function() {
        var keyword = $("#keyword").val();
        if (keyword.length >= MIN_LENGTH) {

            $.get( "auto-complete.php", { keyword: keyword } )
            .done(function( data ) {
                $('#results').html('');
                var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $(results).each(function(key, value) {
                    $('#results').append('<a href="/' + value.slug + '/' + value.id + '/"><div class="item">' + value + '</div></a>');
                })

                $('#keywordsearch').click(function() {
                    var text = $(this).html();
                    $('#keyword').val(text);
                })

            });
        } else {
            $('#results').html('');
        }
    });

    $("#keyword").blur(function(){
            $("#results").hide();
        })
        .focus(function() {     
            $("#results").show();
        });

});
```

This is the PHP/SQL

```
function serachForKeyword($keyword) {

$db = getDbConnection();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT title,id,slug FROM `articles` WHERE title LIKE ? ORDER BY title ASC");

$keyword = $keyword . '%';
$stmt->bindParam(1, $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);

$isQueryOk = $stmt->execute();

$results = array();

if ($isQueryOk) {
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
} else {

  trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
}

$db = null; 

return $results;
```

Comment: What does your "results" object look like? After you call jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Comment: How do I find that out?

Comment: After var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
add console.log(results); and look in the javascript console.

Comment: Thanks. It just returns a list containing the values of 'title', not the other two.

Comment: You might want to make sure $.get( "auto-complete.php", { keyword: keyword } ) is returning what your expecting. It sounds like your api call is not working the way you think it is. For example, you could just put "auto-complete.php" in your address bar at the end of your site name ie `http://localhost:3000/auto-complete.php?keyword=**yourkeywordhere***` you should see your "data".

Comment: Again it only returns the title values. I've edited the original question to include the PHP/SQL in case that's at fault. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO::FETCH_COLUMN tells the driver to just get one column, in your case the title. Try a different fetch mode.

Comment: Yikes, PHP, I'm out!

Comment: Haha.  Yeah, I'm not a php fan either, I just got curious about that constant and googled it.

Comment: Changed it to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and changed `value` to `value.title` and it's working perfectly. Thanks for your help.